# Quiz question amount based on category in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how I can add questions based on player amount selection. For e.g, if the player chooses to have a quiz with 40 questions. These 40 questions should contain 30% math, 14% sport, 6% cities, and so on. Until they sum up to 40 questions.

The quiz should add up too the amount the player selected. Those category only reperesent how much of a category is present in the quiz.

Here is my code:

```
category = {
    "Math": 30,
    "Sport": 14,
    "Citys": 6,
    "Games": 3,
    "Inventions": 3
}

questions = []
amount = int(input("How many questions would you like? "))
for x in range(amount):
    #if ??
    questions.append(x)
```

Comment: First of all, you should have consistent types in your dictionary.

Comment: Will your "percentages" finally add up to 100? Or are these just ratios?

Comment: No they dont add up to 100, should add up to the amount the player selected. Those category only reperesent how much of a category is present in the quiz

Comment: Then, please [edit] the question to make that clear and also fix the data types

Comment: I've updated it, the data type was a misstake

Comment: They're not percents if they don't add to 100. And if you expect the numbers to add up to the number the user chose, why ask the user at all?

Comment: @interjay: the values in `category` make up the distribution ratio, not the number of questions per category, IMHO. As you can see, the categories add up to 56, but the user shall get 40 questions only.

Comment: @ThomasWeller OP said the numbers "should add up to the amount the player selected.". Nothing about them being a ratio. There are many things wrong with this question and summing to the wrong number seems to be one of them.

Comment: By futher testing, the selected amount does sometimes sum up wrong. It's like @interjay says.

Sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some things before you start.

That dictionary at the beginning contains different types. If you want to calculate, use `int`, not `string`. It should be named `categories` instead of `category` as well, because there are many of them.

```
categories = {
    "Math": 30,
    "Sport": 14,
    "Citys": 6,
    "Games": 3,
    "Inventions": 3
}
```

If the numbers don't add up to 100, we need to know what it sums up to:

```
ratioTotal = sum(categories.values())
```

Ask the user, as before:

```
questions = []
totalQuestionCount = int(input("How many questions would you like? "))
```

Then, you need a loop to loop over all the categories, so you get questions for each category (note how the singular and plural starts to make sense):

```
for category, relativeAmount in categories.items():
```

Next, calculate how many questions are needed for a specific category:

```
    amountForCategory = round(totalQuestionCount * relativeAmount / ratioTotal)
```

And start adding questions. Since you don't need a variable, use `_` as the discard variable:

```
    for _ in range(amountForCategory):
        question = GetQuestion(category)
        questions.append(category)
```

At the end you might be off by a few due to rounding errors, so you need to compensate that:

```
while len(questions) < totalQuestionCount:
    question = GetQuestion("any")
    questions.append(question)
```

Left for you: implement the actual questions

```
def GetQuestion(category):
    return "whatever"
```

Comment: Looks great, very nicely explained and this is what i looked for!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it in this way. Since there is no list for the actual questions, I will append the type of the question:

```
category = {
    "Math": 30,
    "Sport": 14,
    "Citys": "6",
    "Games": "3",
    "Inventions": 3
}
scale = 0
for i in category:
    scale += i

questions = []
amount = int(input("How many questions would you like? "))

for i in category:
    temp = [i]*(category[i]*amount//scale)
    questions += temp
#print(temp)
```

Comment: That is the thing: The categoriesshould not add up too 100, they should add up to the amount the player selected. Those category only reperesent how much questions of a category is present in the quiz

Comment: I saw your comment and edited the code

Comment: Still didn't understand though. If there are 56 questions, then there has to be `30` maths, `14` sport etc right. That is how categories should. So they are ratios?

Comment: No there has not to be 30, math should reperesent the majority. If you would like to say 30%

Sorry for my english, i try to explain best i can